# How to send email from my website

Tags: spring, email, spring-mvc, servlets

I am developing a website/web appliaction. Now I have to send different emails to users, like after they register, or if they have any notification or if they forget their password and do password reset.

I will be hoisting it with some web hoisting website. I already had word with them and they will provide me with some email ids, like support@mywebsitename.com.

But I still have to write functionality to send email and I am not getting idea how exactly to go ahead with that. Almost all other things are done. I am passing email id, subject, message to the method. But how exactly to go ahead now.

Please help. I am using Spring MVC .

Comment: @LutzHorn, I think he is looking for full implementation.

Comment: This topic is also too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a SMTP server details which you get them from your provider to send an email from the application.  And Using the Spring frame work it is quite easy to develop the mail functionality. Here is the [Spring Mail](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/27/send-email-with-spring-javamailsenderimpl-example/) where you get injection and code example.  Before that you need to get some details from your service provider, like host name, port etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and beautiful tutorial by mkyong on how to send Email via Spring Mail that I used: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/

Add JavaMail to your dependencies - configure the the mail settings in you spring-config once you have your credentials - create a MailService class where you use MailSender with SimpleMailMessage.